# Why Error? Debug and Code Shown - Running In Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

Okay, so I'm really getting angry with these sudden errors im coming through. Its just really I never experienced them before. I run in logcat and its showing me the error on the line but i dont know why its giving an error!

Here is the full image:

[image: Valid XHTML].

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if("000000000000000".equals(tm.getDeviceId())) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Emulator Worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Emulator Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
    }
}
```

Anyone can please point out the problem that im failing to see? If i used "try", i just get more unexplained errors popping up in Eclipse.

Comment: Are you supposed to have an extra set of brackets around the `TelephonyManager` section?  That doesn't look like it's ran in the `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 1):

Have you declared the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

in manifest file

Comment: Yup, i did that and added alot more non needed permissions just to be sure

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting an exception thrown is because the line

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

cannot be called before the activity's `onCreate()` method is called by your application.  If you look at your parentheses, you will see that the call is outside the `onCreate()` method and therefore gets run during object instantiation.  Correct your parentheses so that the `TelephonyManager` is created inside of `onCreate()`.

In other words:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        if("000000000000000".equals(tm.getDeviceId())) { 
            Toast.makeText(this, "Emulator Worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } 
        else { 
            Toast.makeText(this, "Emulator Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }  
    } 
}
```